# If |a-b| <  and |c-d| < , is it possible to say anything about |ac - bd|?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $|ac - bd| < \varepsilon$ and I can show that $|a-b|$ and $|c-d|$ are arbitrarily small.

Additional note: $b$ and $d$ are constants while $a$ and $c$ are not.

Comment: Consider $ac-bd=c(a-b)+b(c-d)$

Comment: That helps a lot with the proof thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Take $a < c$, $a = b + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $d = c + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then

$$
|ac - bd| = ac - bd = bc + \frac{c}{2}\epsilon - bc - \frac{b}{2}\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{2}(c - b)
$$

which can be unbounded, since you can just take $b = 0$ and $c$ to be arbitrarily big.

Comment: Are you sure this is a genuine ‘nope’? $|ac-bd|<\epsilon(b-c)$ is a useful bound in many situations: if $b,c$ are constant and $\epsilon$ arbitrary, it is good enough!

Comment: @FShrike I just realised he asked different questions in the title and the body of the question... Anyways, for his question of proving $|ac - bd| < \epsilon$, he didn't specify any additional constraint, so for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the condition given, the results proven are not sufficient to say much. but you are correct that if $b$ and $c$ are fixed, then as my answer shows as well, $|ac - bd|$ can be arbitrary small.

Answer (score 0):

$$|a - b| < \epsilon \iff -\epsilon < a - b < \epsilon \iff b - \epsilon < a < b + \epsilon.$$

Similarly, you can conclude that

$$d - \epsilon < c < d + \epsilon.$$

For simplicity, assume that

- $\epsilon > 0$
- $0 < (d - \epsilon), (b - \epsilon).$

Then, you can conclude that

$$bd - \epsilon(b + d) + \epsilon^2 < ac < bd + \epsilon(b + d) + \epsilon^2.$$

This implies that

$$-\epsilon(b+d) - \epsilon^2 < -\epsilon(b+d) + \epsilon^2 < (ac - bd) < \epsilon(b+d) + \epsilon^2.$$

This implies that

$$|ac - bd| < \epsilon(b+d) + \epsilon^2.$$